# Dojo firebug in Firefox 6

Tags: firefox, dojo, firebug, firefox6

I recently started using the [Dojo firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/DojoFirebugExtension_Reference_Guide). I had gotten used to it since it had some nice features (letting you see dojo on the widget level). This was good for me because I am in the process of trying to learn dojo so this really let me see how stuff worked together.

My question is, has anyone found any solutions to get the Dojo firebug extension working in Firefox 6 or should I just try downgrading to FF5?

Thanks

UPDATE: 
I tried a workaround I found somewhere else. It said to use the Firefox nightly build add-on, and that add-on would allow me to override the version compatibility. I tried that and it still didn't work.

Comment: I have tired the both methods (add-on compatibility and the nightly build add-on) and it does not work. I guess will have to wait for the next release. Thank you anyway for the tip about the dojo extension!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend trying the [Add-on Compatibility Reporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/?src=api) extension from Mozilla.  This extension (besides letting you report incompatible add-ons) lets you completely disable version checking.

It's a great way to ensure that older extensions still work when Firefox upgrades the browser every week.  Now, this assumes that the issue is with version compatibility, and not that the plugin *is actually broken*!  If it's the latter, there's not much else you can do.

(Also, that's an awesome plugin.  I'm definitely going to try it out myself here shortly!)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out on monday and let you know how it works.

Comment: Sorry, I tried this out and it works, but it doesn't solve my problem. The add on allowed me to use dojo firebug, but dojo firebug doesn't seem to be working and hence my question of using dojo firebug in firefox is still unanswered. I did give you a vote up though.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work.  I actually kinda figured it was truly broken (as sica07 mentions above).  Hopefully they get it fixed.